# Ajax request when we click on the dropdown list element

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

Friends I created a drop-down list using the following code using js .

```
<script>
  $('.menu').dropit();
</script>

    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Product_name</a>
            <ul>
                <? foreach($customer_details as $details){?>
                <li><a href="#"><?echo $details->name;?></a></li>
                <?}?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The problem is that when the user clicks on the link of the dropdown list I need to send the result ie is the

> $details->name

through an ajax request to a function in the controller (using codeignitor framework).Hoe this is done ??

JS SOURCE : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eoxhp

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('.menu ul  li a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from triggering a pageload
  var productName = $(this).html();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url, // the url you want to send it to
    data: {name: productName },
    success: function() {
      // do whatever you need to do on success
    }
  });
});
```

on the server side you'll be able to access the product name using `$_POST['name']`;

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this...

```
// In your HTML replace the line with this
<li><a onclick="sendInfo(this);" href="#"><?echo $details->name;?></a></li>

// JS
function sendInfo(aEl){
    var val = $(aEl).text();

    $.ajax({
        url : "your url", 
        data : {"name" : val}
    }).done(function(){
        // Success. Do something
    });

}
```

Comment: why would you add a javscript function call directly into the html code?

Comment: It should be understood. You should have the basic understanding of how JS/HTML works.

Comment: i do understand what it's supposed to do but it's not really best practice. what if you decide to change the function name or namespace your code? never teach bad coding practices

Comment: No, I meant to say that, I have just provided the solution. Its up to you to either put into it in a separate file or in the head/body section of your HTML. You may change the function name or namespace however you want, but the logic should remain the same and that's what I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ajax request on change of drop down it works fine for me
i hope that it will also solve your problem.

```
<select name="all_users" id="all_users" onchange="Mehdi_ajax(this.value);">
<option value=""><?=$this->lang->line('global_all')?></option>
<?php if($all_users)
      {
         foreach($all_users->result() AS $item=>$val)
         {
            ?>
             <option value="<?=$val->uid?>"><?=$val->username?></option>
           <?php
         }
      }
      ?>
</select>
```

script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var surl = '<?=secure_xss()?>';
function Mehdi_ajax(id)
{ 

    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: surl+"movable/jewelry/get_all",
    data: "userid=" + id,
    success: function(result){
        $("#Mehdi_ajax").html(result);
    }
    });

}
```